# How to add search box to drupal page contents (404 page)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, http-status-code-404, search-box, search-form

I have a theme where search box is hard to find.

Before redesigning it, I'd like to add another, bigger search box to 404 page.

The only solution I found is render search block:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 97);
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

This is not good solution because one have to find block number first.

How to use [search_box()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_box/7) function properly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd want to try using http://drupal.org/project/search404? I'm not sure if you can disable automatic searching on a 404 page but it's very close to what you are needing without custom code.

Comment: On review of the module you can in fact enable the option to 'Disable automatically searching for the keywords when a page is not found and instead show the populated search form with the keywords. Useful for large sites to reduce server loads.'

Comment: How did I miss this module?

I was thinking too narrow.. I just migrated a joomla site to drupal, and too lazy to setup a thousand of redirects (pages are not 1-to-1).

Installed a search404 module, slightly hacked it to my needs. Now it fits perfectly.